# Dimension architecture - Manufacturing Process

Tags: database-design, architecture, data-warehouse

As part of a design of DWH architecture for a production floor, I need to design a dimension – Dim Manufacturing Process, that will store all the process and the items that are manufactured in those process.

A bit of background and context:

- We have 8 machines (stations) at the production floor
- The production flow is moving in an ascending order, from machine no.1 to machine no.8
- For each item, there is an ordered sequence of the machines that represents the machines that takes
  part in its manufacturing
- Each item has a unique manufacturing sequence (one to one)
- Each manufacturing sequence could have several items (one to many)

My only data source is an output file, that is generated by the end of the day, this is an example for a single item:

[image]

So we can see that the item manufacturing sequence is 1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8

(the decrease in quantity is due to defects – that are detracted from the manufacturing process)

My thought on this was – by utilizing pivot method to create a unique identifier for each manufacturing sequence, for instance 1578 (in our example). The problem that for each manufacturing sequence, there are several items that could be produced utilizing it.

What are the best practices in this case?

Comment: The DWH design always address the reporting requirements which you didn't mention, so it is hard to advice. Your base data are on the *item per machine* level, so the next possible level would be an aggregated table on the level *item per sequence* with attributes: item_id, manufacturing_seq_id (eg 1578), start + end time, total duration, processing_duration, initial_quantity, final_quantity.

Comment: *Each item has a unique manufacturing sequence*. I'll not trust this, I assume if e.g. on machine_id = 7 you'll drop down to zero quantity, you'll not get the data from machine_id = 8, so the *effective manufacturing sequence* will be 157.

Comment: Theoretically you right, effectively a sequence that hasn't been finalized...won't become a sequence (won't get a Final Idn). You can standardize it by simply omitting 0 quantity manufacturing steps and retracting those to a "defects" table.

Comment: Just to emphasise the first comment, this question is unanswerable as you haven't provided your reporting requirements: what are the facts you are trying to measure, what are the attributes that you want to slice-and-dice those facts by, etc?